# Отправка запроса на сервер с помощью socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Добрый день пытаюсь запустить на winginx чат на node.js из вот [этой](http://habrahabr.ru/post/127525/) статьи.
Следующая проблема возникает

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://127.0.0.1:8080/socket.io/1/?t=1351738224902"
```

уже весь интернет облазил понять не могу в чем проблема.

Answer (score 1):

не совсем 8080 winginx у меня занял http сервер по этому когда прописал для nodejs 8081 порт все заработало

Answer (score 0):

Тестируем на домашнем компьютере?  http://127.0.0.1 - вот где ошибка